# MVC Structuring views

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

[yii2 guide structure-views](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-views.md)

I have read the best practices from the link above,

My question is :

We assume that we have a complicated view divided into several smaller ones, and each one contain a from need for a new model

It is interesting to instantiate each model in his form view instead of pushing from the controller all the new record models to the main view, than dispatch those models on their appropriate view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing new models should be done in controllers, views are only for displaying data.

Even if you need to repeat some of passing params in case of nested views, seems like it's right approach which doesn't violate MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If views are independent you may consider extracting them as widgets - you will be able to instantiate required models inside of widget and keep views clean at the same time.